# Como cerrar un formulario al cumplir un horario si el horario es de 7:00 am a 5:00 pm

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un label asociado a un timer y este esta corriendo con el reloj, entonces quiero cerrar un formulario cuando sea la hora asignada en la condicion, si son las 7:00 am que se cierre y muestre un mensaje donde finaliza el turno y si la hora es 5:06 pm que mande un mensaje y abra el formulario de segundo turno?

utilizo 2 formularios y y label
formulario 1 se llama caja_Llena
formulario 2 se llama cajaVacia
label 1 se llama lbl_Hora y esta asiciado a un timer

```
lbl_Hora.text = datetime.now.tostring("hh:mm:ss")
```

La parte de codigo que utilizo es corriendo un timer en una etiqueta llamada lbl_Hora.text.

```
private sub FrmCajaLlena_load(sender as object, e as eventargs) handles mybase.load
        if lbl_Hora.tex >= "07:00:00 AM" and lbl_Hora.text <= "05:00:00 PM" Then
        msgbox("Fin de turno 1")
me.close
        elseif lbl_Hora.text >= "05:06:00 PM" and lbl_Hora.text <= "02:15:00 AM" Then
        msgbox("Bienvenidos al Turno 2")
CajaVacia.show
        end if
    end sub
```

Pero no me esta funcionando la segunda opcion, solo cierra el formulario 1 pero no abre el form2.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ni idea qué será `form2`. Tampoco es evidente si sale algo en logs cuando corres ese código.

Comment: La pregunta o apoyo es el si existe otra sintaxis que me pueda ayudar a solucionar la falla del por que no abre el segundo form al cumplir la condicion de hora asignada?

Comment: Tengo mucho codigo y solo quise resumir a esta sintaxis pero aqui pondre a donde lo estoy mandando llamar.

Comment: Pon en las etiquetas en qué lenguaje estás trabajando. El IDE (Visual Studio) nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Además, debes adjuntar un [repro].

Comment: a ver.. la pregunta, esta toda mal.. no sabemos que es timeofday.. suponemos por el codigo que es un string. NO, POR FAVOR NO COMPARES ASI... transforma las fechas a fechas (u horas) y comparalas como horas normales.. asi, como estas, te vas a meter en montones de lios... despues.. tengo 3 etiquetas que no me dicen que lenguaje es.. si no una ide... Sabias que en esa ide se puede programar en c, c++, f#, c#, java y muchisimos mas.. ah, y por supuesto, vb.net, que es lo que estas usando aca... pero no nos estasn contando....

Comment: Luego.. tu principal problema es comparar los strings asi. Si cambias la forma de comparacion, se acaban todos tus problemas... Pero tu pregunta dice "como cerrar un form al cumplir un horario" y el codigo que mostras, se ejecuta solo cuando se abre el form y se cierra (si la comparacion estuviera bien). Cual es tu pregunta real? usa el boton [edit] y ayudanos a ayudarte arreglando todo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Como lo planteas actualmente el formulario **CajaLlena** controla el label **lbl_Hora**, al momento de cerrar el formulario **CajaLlena** se pierde el timer que abriría el formulario **CajaVacia**, por este motivo no abre el segundo formulario.

Necesitas un tercer formulario que esté siempre corriendo para poder controlar la apertura y cierre de los otros dos y en este formulario incluir el timer. Dentro del if del timer debes validar que no estén ya abiertos los formularios para evitar un bucle de aperturas y no olvides agregar un evento load en los formularios **CajaLlena** y **CajaVacia**.

Comment: Muchaa gracias por la ayuda.